# How to access User.Identity.GetUserId() in Class library

Tags: asp.net-identity, console-application, class-library

I am going to use a class library as a data layer in my mvc.net web application. Is it possible to access User.Identity.GetUserId() from within the class library.

I can access username by using HttpContext.Current.User.Name but not UserId.

Meanwhile, Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity reference is not accessible in class library project.

thanks

Comment: If you are going to use *GetUserId()* extension method. You have to add a *Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity* reference.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just added Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll to my console application references. Unfortunately this reference does not exist in list of References nor in Extensions. I borrowed it from my web application's bin folder.
I'm wondering why Microsoft has not added this in the list of references!